# What is { get } and why do I get an "expected '{' to start getter definition" error?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
func getUserProfile(uid: String, complition:@escaping(user?) -> Void{ 
        var ref : Firestore { get }
}
```

what is { get } in second line of code and why i am getting error  "expected '{' to start getter definition" error?

DO the get property need any code block?

Comment: Hi Jules, can you provide more context? Seems the code snippet is broken, can you update the formatting? Also, if you've got a pointer where you got the snippet from, that'd be helpful. Thanks!